# Github API: Finding untagged commits

Tags: github, github-api

Is it possible to find all untagged commits since the latest release using Github API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can get the [latest release with the GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-the-latest-release) (which matches the matest tag)

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases/latest
```

That means you can then [compare two commits](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits):

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/compare/:base...:head
```

For example: https://api.github.com/repos/git-for-windows/git/compare/v2.4.5.windows.1...master

Notes:

1. See [Working with large comparisons](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#working-with-large-comparisons):

   > The response will include a comparison of up to 250 commits.
   >   If you are working with a larger commit range, you can use the [Commit List API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository) to enumerate all commits in the range.
2. This assume your release was done on the `master` branch (but you [can create a release on another branch](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/))