# GitHub API: Tag a commit belongs to ( parallel for git describe --tag <sha> )

Tags: ruby, git, github, github-api, octokit

I am experimenting with GitHub API using [octokit](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb) ruby gem. My goal is to be able to extract the 'tag' that a commit SHA belongs to.

Now I can easily do this on command line using

`> git describe 688ae0b --tags`

and get output

`> 3.0.1-122-g688ae0b`

which tells me Tag, commits since tags, and last commit hash.

**How do I get same info from GitHub API?**

Answers using GitHub API or Octokit client would both do, as I can translate from one other just fine.

I have looked at a bunch of things like, releases, tags, commits etc.. but none of them give me this information that I can get in one line from command line.

I am not looking for 'how to use github api'. I am looking for specific request or set of requests that will let me derive this information.

Answer (score 3):

Since there is no easy way to run a query like git describe with the GitHub API, that leaves you with an iterative process involving:

- [listing all tags](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-tags)
- trying to diff a tag against your specific commit, with the [compare 2 commits API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits)

  ```
  GET /repos/:owner/:repo/compare/:base...:head
  ```

(with base being the commit, and head being the tag)

If there are any result, the commit is accessible from the tag.

(I use a similar approach in "[Github API: Finding untagged commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31634852/6309)")

Comment: Thanks @VonC. That seems like a good way to proceed.  I will try it out and see how it goes..

Comment: Can you think of any other way without using GitHub API, but not having to have a local clone? May be something with ls-remote? I am looking to write a web-service that can inform the version of the project itself and show it in the footer. I can easily do this using capistrano, but then version will only get bumped when project is deployed..

Comment: @Shaunak not really. Having an updated local copy of the repo remains the surest way to get that kind of information.

Comment: @VonC, is this answer still actual nowadays?

Comment: @elect do you mean still current? Apparently so. Maybe with graphql V4 you might have better results.